# How to Embed HTML Like JSFiddle?

Tags: html, embed, output

I'm looking for a way to embed an html output. Like I want to write an article like this:

"
when you write `<p>A <strong>bold</strong> text</p>`,

you get an output like   A **bold** text .
"

So I want to do this programmaticcally like:

"
when you write `<p>A <strong>bold</strong> text</p>`,

you get an output like  `<div class='embedded_html_output'><p>A <strong>bold</strong> text</p></div>`
"

I hope I made myself clear.

Is there a javascript or php plugin for this?

Thanks !

Comment: are you looking for some thing like this? http://www.psd2html.com/examples/markup/michaeldferrell/index.html?title=Michael+D.+Ferrell

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'd just embed one of these: [Link](http://mashable.com/2008/11/03/embeddable-html-editors/)

They use simple textarea tags and are initialized via javascript.  Google recommends TinyMCE in several places from what I've seen though I've never used any of them personally.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Gist.

> https://gist.github.com/

It is a nice way to embed code to your page as well as share it with a URL.